# Forking Github repo (MIT): what references to original author should remain intact?

Tags: open-source, github, mit-license

I'll pick [one of the most popular react boilerplates](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot) as an example here.

Assume, i've forked it (commits history till fork date remains intact).
According to the text of MIT license, the only thing that I have to keep is the license itself. So, does it mean i can change whatever i want in this repo and remove/replace whatever references to the author (e.g. [package.json author](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/blob/master/package.json#L31)? Except one thing - [reference to original author in the LICENSE file](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/blob/master/LICENSE#L3)

And, also, I should replace [this line](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/blob/master/LICENSE#L3) on top of LICENSE file with this text:

> Copyright for portions of project [Original project name] are held by [original author, year] as part of project [New project name]. All other copyright for project Foo are held by [new name, year].

Are these assumptions correct? Where can I find authoritative explanation of such details of MIT license?

Comment: I would like to know the answer. Can the question be moved to an appropriate site?

Comment: here we go: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6119/forking-github-repo-mit-what-references-to-original-author-should-remain-inta